# How to add a xaml page in the Windows Charms?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I recently submitted my first App to the Windows Store. It was rejected two times. The first one, due to some idioms issues. The second one, due to the fact that the **Privacy Policy** was missing since the App use the Internet **connection capability**.

I added the Privacy Policy as suggested and when the user press the **Windows Key + C** and then click on the Privacy option it opens an url where the Privacy statement is written. It works OK so far.

The thing here, is that despite it works, the way how the Privacy statement is displayed doesn't convince me at all.
I have seen that this behaivor can be achive displaying the Privacy Statement inside the **Windows Charms** instead of open the browser and show it. But here, is where I'm little lost. I'm now sure how to do that.

I've created a new Page.xaml and write the Privacy Statement there. However, as mention I don't know how to show it inside the Windows Charms.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you working with the Callisto Extension? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0526563b-7a48-4b17-a087-a35cea701052

Comment: Hi Smartis. I tried to used the Callisto extension from the Nuget Package in VS. However, I couldn't install it due to a framework incompatibility. I'm working with the framework 4.5 and the error message shows that the Callisto extension is in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a popup with height is your window height and put it where setting panel display. Set your Privacy Statement page to be child of that popup.

At window 8.1 you can try SettingFlyout.